# How to set à priority for security Listeners?

Tags: symfony, symfony-components

I've a Sso authentication on my portal, which bypass the login form if a specific header is present into the request.

When I try to impersonnate a user, the Symfony's Context Listener find the user and load it into security context, then my Sso listener detect header and overwrite the token in the security token. So the impersonnating failed.

I've two idea but I don't know about feasibility:

- is there a way to configure a priority for these security listeners ?
- Is there a way to detect if an authenticated token is already set in security context from Firewall\ListernerInterface's handle method's event ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of listener which uses getSubscriedEvents to set priorities:

```
class ModelEventListener extends ContainerAware implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    const ControllerRoleEventListenerPriority  = -1100;
    const ControllerModelEventListenerPriority = -1900;
    const ControllerFormEventListenerPriority  = -1910;

    const ViewEventListenerPriority = -1900;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(
                array('onControllerRole',  self::ControllerRoleEventListenerPriority),
                array('onControllerModel', self::ControllerModelEventListenerPriority),
                array('onControllerForm',  self::ControllerFormEventListenerPriority),
            ),
            KernelEvents::VIEW => array(
                array('onView', self::ViewEventListenerPriority),
            ),
        );
    }
```

You can also set priority in your services.yml file: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

```
services:
  kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener
    tags:
    - 
      name: kernel.event_listener
      event: kernel.exception
      method: onKernelException
      priority: 666
```

Finally, here are the priorities of some of the framework services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-event-listener

Not sure where the security listener priorities are documented.  They must be around somewhere.  You can always look in the security bundle.

Comment: While those priorities would work they should as they should be between -255 and 255 like the docs say.

Comment: Guess I overlooked that when I created these listeners.  Oh well.